# Tornado reverse_url()

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to use reverse_url() in tornado
and as far as I could understand to use the reverse url I need to add a name to the urls list (just like Django) but from some reason I get Invalid syntax when I'm trying to run the server:

This is my URLS list:

```
urls = [
    (r"/", IndexHandler, name="home"),
]
```

and this is my html:

```
<a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="{{reverse_url('home')}}">
```

and this is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tornado_server.py", line 4, in <module>
  from urls import urls
File "C:\Users\elong\Desktop\reblaze\4. ReactJS\react_tornado\urls.py", line 4
  (r"/", IndexHandler, name="home"),
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To name the urls it's not enough just to pass a list of tuples, instead you need full `URLSpec` objects -- see http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.URLSpec

In your particular example, you can easily use the helper `tornado.web.url` function:

```
from tornado.web import url

urls = [
    url(r"/", IndexHandler, name="home"),
]
```